# HTML tag library functions

Tags: java, namespaces

Let we have Facelet `1.xhtml`. This facelet contains following line
`xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"`
What `"http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` does mean? If we dont internet accesing application will work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a XML namespace. In your case, you are defining a XML namespace prefix `h` with a URI of `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html`. The URI is just a way of uniquely naming the namespace, the parser wont load it, so to answer you question. No. You do not need internet :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace